# What is an elegant way to wrap an error an rethrow in both cases?

Tags: java, kotlin

There is a method which can:

1. throw an error
2. return null

I need to throw a user friendly exception to upper level in the both cases. What is the most elegant way for it? The brute force is:

```
try {
  result = callMethod();
} catch (SomeException e) {
  throw new UserFiendlyException("cannot process you, try again pls");
}
if (result == null) {
  throw new UserFiendlyException("cannot process you, try again pls");
}
```

**UPD 1**: kotlin is accepted and preferable (but I'm also curious how could it be in Java)

**UPD 2**: Please, don't suggest `the use of exceptions for control flow is an anti-pattern`: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: If you put the null check in the try, then you can handle it in the catch. Maybe you can throw a Null Pointer exception.

Comment: Set `result = null;` in the `catch` block? Or assuming `result` is initialised as `null` before the `try` block, the `catch` block could just be empty.

Comment: Do you want a Java solution or a Kotlin one? You code is in Java, but you have also put a Kotlin tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try...catch` and `throw` are expressions in Kotlin, so you can do:

```
val result =
    try {
        callMethod()
    } catch (e: SomeException) {
        null
    } ?: throw UserFiendlyException("cannot process you, try again pls")
```

The `try...catch` will produce `null` if either `callMethod` returns null. or if an exception occurred. We check if it is null using `?:`, and if it is, we throw the user friendly exception.

`result` will end up having a non nullable type.

Comment: I've never used Kotlin before. This is a neat way to funnel exceptions into a single type.

Answer (score 2):

If `callMethod()` is your own method, you could update that to perform the `null` check internally and throw the error...

```js
function callMethod() {
    const responseFromService = null;

    if (responseFromService == null)
        throw new SomeException(`Expected a valid response from the service but got null.`);
}

try {
  result = callMethod();
}
catch (SomeException e) {
  throw new UserFiendlyException("cannot process you, try again pls");
}
```

You can also try the [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#Kotlin)...

```kotlin
try {
  result = callMethod() ?: throw new SomeException(`Escape!`);
}
catch (SomeException e) {
  throw new UserFiendlyException("cannot process you, try again pls");
}
```

Or just keep it simple and check for null within the `try`...

```js
try {
  result = callMethod();
  if (result == null) throw new SomeException(`Escape!`);
}
catch (SomeException e) {
  throw new UserFiendlyException("cannot process you, try again pls");
}
```

Edit: Answer originally had the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) as an option, but the question is for Java, not JavaScript. My bad.

Edit (2): Turns out there is a nullish coalescing operator in Kotlin; option restored.

Comment: Kotlin does have a null coalescing operator, but it's `?:` rather than `??`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator#Kotlin

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've added the option leveraging it back.

Comment: `throw new SomeException(`Escape!`)` to escape the program section and goto another program section (i.e. control program flow) is antipattern (

Comment: @J.J.Beam Agreed. I think the first option is the safest and cleanest. The other options are just options but should be gauged on their adherence to patterns, readability, and maintainability.